Perspective on Differentials Generating Transformations of Functions - with Fourier Transformations $e^{a\partial_x} f(x) = f(x+a)$
An analytic function $f(x)$ can be transformed by the exponential of a differential operator.
The most known and easiest example is
$
e^{a \partial_x} f(x) = f(x+a)
$
Generally this is shown by Taylor series.
Because $f$ is analytic it has a Taylor series $T^{\infty} [f,a](x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}(x-a)^n$.
Now the object $e^{a \partial_x}$ is interpreted by Taylor expansion:
$e^{a \partial_x} f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a^n}{n!} \partial_x^nf(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(x)}{n!}a^n = T^{\infty} [f,x](a+x) = f(x+a)$
This is for example used in Quantum Mechanics:
By Noether-Theorem the momentum operator $\hat{p}$ generates translation.
In real space representation the momentum operator is a differential operator $\hat{p} = -i\hbar \nabla$.
This leads us to $\psi(x+a) = e^{a \frac{i}{\hbar}\hat{p}}\psi(x)$. The argument can be expanded to more then one dimension and I believe that the factors are simply for dimension and unitarity.
From this simple case we can expand to more general differential operators for analytic and invertible functions $g$:
$e^{\frac{d}{dg(x)}}f(x) = f(G(x))$
Using $f(x) = f(g^{-1}(g(x)))$, we can see that $G(x) = g^{-1}(g(x)+1)$.
Because of Cauchy-Eulers differential equations, we may be interested in $e^{\frac{d}{d(ln(x)/a)}}=e^{ax\frac{d}{dx}}$. So $G(x) = e^{a( lnx/a +1)}= e^a x$, and $x \frac{d}{dx}$ gives us scaling instead of translation.
Now the main content:
I want to present an easier argument for the translation by exponentiation of differentiation and then use the same argument for the scaling operator.
Based on the momentum operator argument, I will look at this operator in momentum space ($k$-space).
As Quantum Mechanics (and Fourier Transform) deals with Schwartz functions, so smooth and rapidly decreasing functions, this argument is just for a (very important) subspace of analytic functions.
We need two pieces of information before the argument becomes evident:
Be $F(k) = \mathcal{F}(f(x))(k)$ the Fourier transform of f, given it exists and I will be making use of the unitary angular frequency convention.
$1. \mathcal{F}(f(x+a))(k) = e^{ i a k} F(k)$
$2. \mathcal{F}(f'(x))(k) = ik F(k) $
$\implies$
$\mathcal{F}(e^{a\frac{d}{dx}} f(x))(k) = e^{a i k }F(k) = \mathcal{F}(f(x+a))(k)  \\ \implies e^{a \frac{d}{dx}} f(x) = f(x+a)$
The last step is also a property of Schwartz functions.
That I can transform the exponent as shown can be seen by examining the series representation.
I believe this to be a neat proof and would like to have some feedback on the argumentation, possible gaps and additional steps!
Now as a last step, the application to the scaling operator.
$3. \mathcal{F}(f(a x))(k) = \frac{1}{a} F(\frac{k}{a}), a>0$
$4. \mathcal{F}(xf'(x) )(k) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \mathcal{F}(x)(k) * \mathcal{F}(f'(x))(k) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} (i \sqrt{2\pi} \delta'(k) )*(ik F(k) ) = - (kF(k))' = - F(k) - k F'(k) = (-1-k\frac{d}{dk})F(k)$
$\implies$
$ \mathcal{F}(e^{a x\frac{d}{dx}} f(x))(k) = e^{-a-k\frac{d}{dk} }F(k) = e^{-a}F(e^{-a}k) \\ \iff e^{a x\frac{d}{dx}} f(x) = f(e^a x) $
Thanks for reading! I'm open to questions and comments, so I can close remaining argumentative gaps. I hope you liked my perspective on this transformation and find these ideas useful.

This https://dx.doi.org/10.1088/1751-8121/aa6f32 might be helpful to you.

You do not need $f$ to be analytic, in general, spectral theory allows one to consider functions of operators for much more general function spaces, for example $L^2(\Bbb R^d)$.

Indeed, for functions of differential operators, the Fourier transform works well. And actually these operators are usually called "Fourier multipliers". One can prove that $f(\nabla)$ indeed corresponds to multiplying on the Fourier side by $f(x)$. Your proofs seem correct, although it is not needed to use the Dirac delta, and a more rigorous proof (to avoid justifying convolution of distributions etc) would be to just use the fact that $\mathcal{F}(x f') = -i \mathcal{F}(f')'= (x\,\mathcal{F}(f))' = x \mathcal{F}(f)' + \mathcal{F}(f)$.

In the special case of exponential of operators, a definition that is often more useful and more widely applicable than the infinite series is the differential equation : $g(t) := e^{tA}f$ is the solution to
$$
\partial_t g = Ag \quad\text{ with }\quad g(0) = f
$$
at time $t$. For example, the solution to the transport equation $\partial_t g = v\cdot\nabla g$ with initial condition $f$ is $g(t,x) = f(x+tv)$ which gives at $t=1$, $e^{v\cdot\nabla}f(x) = f(x+v)$. And this does not need as much regularity as the infinite series!
For you second operator, the equation is $\partial_t g = a\,x\cdot\nabla g$ and the method of characteristics gives $g(t,x)=f(X_t(x))$ where $X_t(x) = e^{ta}x$ and so
$$
e^{a\,x\cdot\nabla} f(x) = f(e^ax).
$$



Thank you for your comment! I'm quite fond of Dirac delta calculations but your calculation is quite neat - I like it. The concept of "Fourier multipliers" is new to me and sounds quite intriguing. Can you explain why the differential equation approach are more widely applicable (is it a convergence thing and about the ease of calculations?) and what do you mean with "regularity"?

Can this be formulated as a formal proof for the shifting theorem $e^{\mathbf{v}\cdot\nabla}f(\mathbf{x}) = f(\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{v})$
which I found very handy as well?

The differential equation approach is better than Fourier approaches on domains for example, and better than series for less regular data (regular means roughly speaking how many derivatives need to be defined) since series of differential operators need indeed something like analytic functions (so infinitely many derivatives)

@LL 3.14, can you say that differential operator approach can work in Schwartz space?

Yes, in particular
